# О чередующемся корне РОС/РАСТ/РАЩ

Tags: чередования

В глаголе расти – общеславянский корень, современная форма образована из общеславянского  orsti от ordti, того же корня, что и род.

1) Почему в этом корне сохраняются две формы написания А и О (традиция, смысл, отражение фонетического чередования)?

2) Возможно ли изменение этого правила и написание буквы О во всех случаях в соответствии с сильной позицией в слове "рост"?

3) Или, может быть, надо объяснять смысл правила? В противном случае мы будем растить послушных (нетворческих) исполнителей необоснованных правил, и не только на письме, а в любой области науки или просто жизни.

Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написание гласной  в корнях  -рoc(т)-‖-рac(т)  объяснимо лишь историческими причинами.В вариантах -рос(т)- и -рас(т)- представлены русские и старославянские по происхождению написания. Одни из чередующихся корней возникли в результате влияния старославянского языка (например, корни ***рос-, ровн-*** являются русскими, ***а рост-, равн - старославянскими),*** другие отражают старое распределение глаголов по видам (глаголы несовершенного вида на -ать имели в корне а, глаголы совершенного вида на -ить имели в корне о: излагать — изложить). Поскольку в древнерусском языке безударные гласные произносились почти так же, как и ударные (в словах загорать, росла, уложить на месте о произносился звук [о], а не [а]), то и проблемы разграничения на письме этих вариантов корней не было.

В дальнейшем,  при образовании форм несовершенного вида коренной гласный удлинялся;в русском языке это удлинение соответствующим образом видоизменилось: в глаголах несовершенного вида вместо о появлялось ***а.***

Comment: Серж, я не очень поняла ваши объяснения, но дело даже не в этом. Самый важный вопрос: почем мы не пишем РОСТ/РОЩ/РОС, какой смысл отражать на письме чередование А/О в современном языке, если морфы с гласной О можно проверить ударением (рос, рост, пророщенный). Есть ли какой-нибудь довод в пользу сохранения А, кроме традиции, и  достаточное ли это основание, учитывая сложность темы "чередование гласных в корне"  в целом?

Comment: Вера, я писал о том, что эта два разных корня: (ст.-сл. расти – русск. росла).Это традиционные написания(слова пи­шутся так, как их писали в старину),которые ничем не оправданны: ни фонетически, ни морфологически.

Comment: Значит, эти написания нужно отменить, чтоб не создавать путаницу в умах пользователей, в том числе детей. .А то росточек, подростковый, вырост - забыли в исключения внести.  Кстати, "подростковый" явно проверяется "подростком". И почему, кстати, в слове отрасль пишется А, а в слове поросль пишется О?

Comment: У Лопатина есть "росток", "вы́рост, выростно́й, вы́росток". Вера, дело в том, что в обычных ударных- безударных корнях, любая гласная может быть под ударением, так и без ударения. А здесь под ударением может быть только о. Мы же не сможем подобрать родственное слово, где безударный гласный станет ударным.

Comment: А если гласную по смыслу выбирать. В основе семейства -  глагол расти. Из него выделить слово рост и производные от него: рост-росток-ростовщик (дающий деньги в рост). Рост - это фактически ударная перегласовка А/О, неудобно говорить "раст".  Хотя бы какое-то внятное объяснение. Сравнить: загореть - загар, нагореть - нагар, тоже перегласовка.

Comment: Вера, можно и так. Но возможно ли это сейчас? Ведь хотели в причастиях с зависимыми слово  узаконить одно н, в исключениях после шипящих писать у. ПараШут, жУри и т.д. Это вызвало массу протестов. Думается, и в этом случае было бы то же самое.

Comment: Серж, я уже в своем ответе написала о том, как бы мне хотелось объяснить  это правило.

Comment: Да, я читал. Вера, ваше правило логично, но насколько легко его будет запомнить школьникам - не знаю. В любом случае, наши с вами дискуссии здесь бесполезны.О таких вещах надо писать в Институт Русского языка.

Comment: Правило остается тем же для тех, кто не задает вопросы, а привык все принимать на веру и заучивать наизусть. А разъяснение правила - материал факультативный, для думающих пользователей. Писать же в Институт Русского языка - это все равно что обращаться к инопланетному разуму, да и то оттуда ответ придет быстрее и с большей заинтересованностью в дискуссии.

Comment: Ответ скорее всего придет, вот только слушать нас никто не станет. ))

Answer (score 1):

```
   это ФОРМАЛЬНОЕ ПРАВИЛО. Это значит, что этим правилом мы ничего 
    не   объясняем, ничего не назначаем. Оно помогает ЗАПОМНИТЬ 
    выбор   нужной формы, и это его единственное назначение.
```

Думаю, не единственное. Есть ещё назначение - память об исторических корнях.Дети должны видеть русские по происхождению слова и заимствования.Чередования корней -рос- // -раст- ведут свое начало, от общеславянского * orst, которое в древнерусском языке имеет в начале ро-, а в старославянском – ра-: рост (др.-рус.) – растение (ст.-слав.), рослый (др.-рус.) – выращивать (ст.-слав.), подросток (др.- рус.) – произрастать (ст.-слав.) и др.Вариант -рос(т)- имеет ударный гласный: рост, рос; в варианте -рас(т)- гласный безударный, и написание а является здесь традиционным-это старославянизм. Практические рекомендации по выбору букв о или а в этом корне таковы: Корень рас(т)- пишется в глаголах расти, растить, вырастать, наращать и т. п. и во всех образованных от них словах, например: растение, произрастание, ращение, сращение, возраст и т. п., а также в слове отрасль(старославянизмы); корень рос(т)- пишется в прошедшем времени и в причастии прошедшего времени от расти, например: рос, росла, росло, росший, вырос, выросший и т. п., а также в словах заросль, поросль, водоросль, недоросль, росток и в образованных от них словах - русизмы.
Есть стихотворения С. Крыжановского.

Отчего, обжигая горло,

Разбирая часами подряд

Сочетания «оло» и «оро» –

«Вран» и «ворон», «молод» и «млад»?

Человек некий ими два сына...

Я прислушиваюсь к словам.

Открывается в них Россия,

Легендарная быль славян...

Сто-ро-на. Го-ло-са. До-ро-га.

Я усвоил твёрдо азы:

С давних лет к открытости слога

Тяготел славянский язык.

Мы же говорим о возрождении национального самосознания, а Вы предлагаете снивелировать русские и заимствованные слова - пусть пишутся одинаково. Я - против.Пусть уж дети потрудятся и запомнят правило, хотя бы историю языка знать будут.А то , может, и град и город сделать одинаковыми?

Comment: Людмила, я не предлагала ничего нивелировать, просто задала ДИСКУССИОННЫЙ вопрос, чтобы ЗАИНТЕРЕСОВАТЬ аудиторию и вместе со всеми ОБСУДИТЬ такую возможность. В ходе общего обсуждения  выяснилось,  что использовать одну форму с гласной О НЕ ПРЕДСТАВЛЯЕТСЯ ВОЗМОЖНЫМ, так как 90% существующих написаний - это глаголы  с корнем РАСТ/РАЩ, а корень РОС/РОС - это ПОБОЧНАЯ ВЕТКА, обусловленная УДАРНОЙ ПОЗИЦИЕЙ корней РОС/РОС.  (Вы же в качестве причины существования двух форм называете  желание отличить СТАРОСЛАВЯНИЗМЫ ОТ ИСКОННО РУССКИХ СЛОВ ).

Comment: Таким образом, определилась общая картина и СТАЛИ ПОНЯТНЫ ПРАВИЛА, которые да этого просто  заучивались и не понимались, судя по предыдущей дискуссии на эту тему. Далее я делаю вывод о том, что теперь понимание достигнуто, но в виде рассуждения правило неудобно для использования. И говорю о формальном правиле, которое ХОРОШО ЗАПОМИНАЕТСЯ И КОТОРЫМ СЛЕДУЕТ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЬСЯ, но при этом это правило не отвечает на вопрос "почему", а  «почемучкам» следует  дополнительно (факультативно)  ознакомиться с рассуждением на тему.

Comment: Что касается детей, то, конечно, желательно, чтобы они любили родной язык, но также хотелось бы видеть их ТВОРЧЕСКИМИ И ДУМАЮЩИМИ людьми, способными развивать российскую науку. И знаете, русская орфография могла бы внести существенный вклад в воспитание нового поколения россиян. Память об исторических корнях – это прекрасно, но  орфография – наука практическая, а пока результаты усвоения ОЧЕНЬ ПРОСТОГО ПРАВИЛА весьма плачевны, например:  «Я так и не понял: слово "рост" - не исключение, а О пишется после гласной СТ.  Молодой лес это растуший лес или ростущий лес?»

Answer (score 0):

Всё-таки полезная вещь - общественные дискуссии, даже не получив прямого ответа, что-то изменяешь в своем мнении.

Мне кажется, что эта тема в школе должна излагаться следующим образом.

1) Вследствие особенностей исторического развития языка, в корне РАСТ/РАЩ/РОС/РОСТ происходит чередование гласных  А/О, совпадающее с фонетическим чередованием, которое отражается на письме.

В настоящий момент (согласно словообразовательным словарям) исходным словом для семейства родственных слов является глагол РАСТИ, и практически большую часть семейства составляют производные глаголы с различными приставками, в которых пишется корень РАСТ/РАЩ.

2) Корень РОСТ/РОС является исключением и связан с УДАРНОЙ позицией гласного О: маленький рост, щенок рос, лес зарос/порос. Слова, производные от этих форм, сохраняют гласную О: росток (побег, начинающий рост), ростовщик (дающий деньги в рост), росточек, костюм на вырост (с учетом роста).

Также: заросли, поросль - слова, образованные от формы "рос". Слово "отрасль" по семантике отличается от этих слов.

Ростов, Ростислав - имена собственные.

3) Существующее правило выбора гласной ( А - перед СТ и Щ, О - перед С, кроме исключений) запомнить несложно, оно УДОБНО ДЛЯ ПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ, но надо хорошо понимать, что это ФОРМАЛЬНОЕ ПРАВИЛО. Это значит, что этим правилом мы ничего  не объясняем, ничего не назначаем. Оно помогает ЗАПОМНИТЬ выбор нужной формы, и это его единственное назначение.